# Special simple and triple arrow styles with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arrows

I need to create arrows with the following styles:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I couldn't find packages that made them directly as symbols, So I decided to use the *tikz* package and the tikz library *shapes.arrows*. It was my first time using this package, but I think I managed to get the first one as follows:

```
\newcommand*{\tikzarrow}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=-2.5pt]
  \node[
    single arrow, single arrow head extend=4pt, draw, inner sep=5pt, top color=white, minimum height=0.7cm]{#1};
}
```

Using *\tikzarrow{}* I got the following:
[image]
I haven't been able to do the other arrows... I'd also like to know if there's another simpler or more efficient way to do the first arrow.

I need them to use in paragraphs, equations, and alpha graphs made with pstricks...

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just styles for arrows with line in the middle:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
STA/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=4pt, draw,
              inner sep=5pt, minimum height=7mm,
              append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                                    \draw  (\LN.west) -- (\LN.east);}
                                    }       
              }, 
DTA/.style = {double arrow, double arrow head extend=4pt, draw,
              inner sep=5pt, minimum height=11mm,
              append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                                    \draw  (\LN.west) -- (\LN.east);}
                                    }
              }
                    ]
\node[STA]  {}; \node[DTA] at (2,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
And one example of use this arrows in a `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 11mm,
  start chain = going right,
  C/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=11mm},
STA/.style = {single arrow, single arrow head extend=4pt, draw,
              inner sep=5pt, minimum height=7mm,
              append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                                    \draw  (\LN.west) -- (\LN.east);}
                                    }       
              }, 
DTA/.style = {double arrow, double arrow head extend=4pt, draw,
              inner sep=5pt, minimum height=11mm,
              append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                                    \draw  (\LN.west) -- (\LN.east);}
                                    }
              }
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes=on chain]
\node[C]    {};
\node[STA]  {}; 
\node[C]    {};
\node[DTA]  {};
\node[C]    {};
\end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! :)